# how to get a pattern repeating multiple times in a string using regular expression

Tags: python, regex, nltk

I am still new to regular expressions, as in the Python library `re`.

I want to extract all the proper nouns as a whole word if they are separated by space.

I tried

```
result = re.findall(r'(\w+)\w*/NNP (\w+)\w*/NNP', tagged_sent_str)
```

Input: I have a string like

```
tagged_sent_str = "European/NNP Community/NNP French/JJ European/NNP export/VB"
```

Output expected:

```
[('European Community'), ('European')]
```

Current output:

```
[('European','Community')]
```

But this will only give the pairs not the single ones. I want all the kinds

Comment: What should happen if there are three (or more) consecutive NNPs?

Comment: It should give all the consecutive NNPs together

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting requirement. Code is explained in the comments, a very fast solution using only `REGEX`:

```
import re
# make it more complex
text = "export1/VB European0/NNP export/VB European1/NNP Community1/NNP Community2/NNP French/JJ European2/NNP export/VB European2/NNP"


# 1: First clean app target words word/NNP to word,
#  you can use str.replace but just to show you a technique
# how to to use back reference of the group use \index_of_group
# re.sub(r'/NNP', '', text)
# text.replace('/NNP', '')
_text = re.sub(r'(\w+)/NNP', r'\1', text)

# this pattern strips the leading and trailing spaces
RE_FIND_ALL = r'(?:\s+|^)((?:(?:\s|^)?\w+(?=\s+|$)?)+)(?:\s+|$)'
print('RESULT : ', re.findall(RE_FIND_ALL, _text))
```

OUTPUT:

```
  RESULT :  ['European0', 'European1 Community1 Community2', 'European2', 'European2']
```

Explaining REGEX:

- `(?:\s+|^)` : skip leading spaces
- `((?:(?:\s)?\w+(?=\s+|$))+)`: capture a group of non copture subgroup `(?:(?:\s)?\w+(?=\s+|$))` subgroup will match all sequence words folowed by spaces or end of line. and that match will be captured by the global group. if we don't do this                               the match will return only the first word.
- `(?:\s+|$)` : remove trailing space of the sequence

I needed to remove `/NNP` from the target words because you want to keep the sequence of `word/NNP` in a single group, doing something like this  `(word)/NNP (word)/NPP` this will return two elements in one group but not as a single text, so by removing it the text will be `word word` so REGEX `((?:\w+\s)+)` will capture the sequence of word but it's not a simple as this because we need to capture the word that doesn't contain `/sequence_of_letter` at the end, no need to loop over the matched groups to concatenate element to build a valid text.

**NOTE**: both solutions work fine if all words are in this format `word/sequence_of_letters`; if you have words that are not in this format
you need to fix those. If you want to keep them add `/NPP` at the end of each word, else add `/DUMMY` to remove them.

Using `re.split` but slow because I'm using `list comprehensive` to fix result:

```
import re
# make it more complex
text = "export1/VB Europian0/NNP export/VB Europian1/NNP Community1/NNP Community2/NNP French/JJ Europian2/NNP export/VB Europian2/NNP export/VB export/VB"

RE_SPLIT = r'\w+/[^N]\w+'
result = [x.replace('/NNP', '').strip() for x in re.split(RE_SPLIT, text) if x.strip()]
print('RESULT:  ', result)
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, `itertools.groupby` is more suited for this kind of job:

```
from itertools import groupby

def join_token(string_, type_ = 'NNP'):
    res = []
    for k, g in groupby([i.split('/') for i in string_.split()], key=lambda x:x[1]):
        if k == type_:
            res.append(' '.join(i[0] for i in g))
    return res

join_token(tagged_sent_str)
```

Output:

```
['European Community', 'European']
```

and it doesn't require a modification if you expect three or more consecutive types:

```
str2 = "European/NNP Community/NNP Union/NNP French/JJ European/NNP export/VB" 

join_token(str2)
```

Output:

```
['European Community Union', 'European']
```

Comment: Thank you Chris for your answer. This works well as required but I was wondering if this can be done with regular expression

Comment: @NancyGoyal You can't use a single regex method call because the texts you want to appear inside a single string result are not adjoining in the input.

Answer (score 0):

You'd like to get a pattern but with some parts deleted from it.
You can get it with two successive regexes:

```
tagged_sent_str = "European/NNP Community/NNP French/JJ European/NNP export/VB"                                      

[ re.sub(r"/NNP","",s) for s in re.findall(r"\w+/NNP(?:\s+\w+/NNP)*",tagged_sent_str) ]                               
['European Community', 'European']
```